# Datadog Create custom metric from another custom metric

Tags: datadog

I have a datadog count metric that I want to create a new metric from which shows the difference between two agent points on the metric, so I can see the change between points.

Is there a way to create a metric from another metric using the datadog dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an ever increasing counter, you can use the a function called [rate](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/functions/rate/). You'll be able to select it with the `+` on the query line. With that you'll be able to have a rate of increase per seconds, minutes or hours.

If you are looking to get a difference between the same metric but at another point in the past, you have a function called [timeshift](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/functions/timeshift/) that could also help. This is also accessible with the small `+` on the right of the query line.

Finally, if you are looking at comparing two different metrics, you  have a button called [Advanced](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/querying/#arithmetic-between-two-metrics) that will enable you to write more complex queries such as a difference between two metrics.

Comment: thanks, do you know if there's a way to create a new metric using the console based on rate

Comment: For what I know, it is not possible to create another metric from an initial one within the Datadog platform. You'll have to submit a different one from you application itself.